# ImportXML with Contains Returning Repeat Data When There is No Class

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Data Source](http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php)

On that page, I am trying to extract "Average Draft Position ----- Based on the 63 Dynasty League Redrafts.", and more specifically, just the number 63.

I am not able to find any class for the div that information resides in (I may be wrong about that however).

I was able to get so far as to use IMPORTXML with contains()....

```
=IMPORTXML("http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php", "//table/tr/td[contains(., 'Average Draft Position')]")
```

However, that returns [image: Data Sample]. Cell A1 goes has a ton of text I didn't bother to include.

When I tried to nest that formula inside a value/regex formula - it returned an insane amount of numbers.

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php","//table/tr/td[contains(., 'Average Draft Position')]"),"[^[:digit:]]", ""))
```

To that end, what do I need to do differently so that my query outputs 63?

Comment: If you want to output only 63 (which if I understand you correctly, represents the last value in the row between headers and names), why don't you do this?: `=IMPORTXML("http://play.fulltimefantasy.com/avgdraftDFWC.php", "//table/tr[3]/td[last()]")`. I'm putting this in a comment for now, because I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: that absolutely works in this instance, my fear is that would break more easily should the site add in an additional row of text. do you have any idea why my query returning multiple rows of data?

Comment: as a follow up - you actually asked why i didn't do what you suggested and the real answer is ... b/c i didn't know that was possible! :-)